# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle

I've initially posted this question on serverfault.com, but because lack of answers decided to post it here...

I'm trying to use bat file/CLI to run SQL script against certain Oracle database with following syntax:

```
sqlplus -L user_name/database_name@Password @d:\my_bat_file\sql_script.sql
```

If I run this following error is returned:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle. Exitig SQL*Plus
```

At the same time **tnsping database_name** works fine & corresponding connection configuration strings are present in tnsnames.ora

Moreover if I type commands manually in a following way:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect user_name@databasename
Passowrd
```

I can connect to the database too. Any idea why I'm getting error when trying to use command I mentioned in beginning & how to fix it?

P.S. I'm doing this from Windows Server 2003 SP2 box with Oracle client v10 installed.

Comment: I hope you mean user_name/password@tnsalias instead of user_name/database_name@Password

Comment: Well - you draw my attention to the right thing... Kind of a stupid mistake. Indeed problem was because I've used username/thsalias@password instead of username/password@tnsalias. Just copied this syntax from previously used batch file - and because it is test environment with the same values for password & tnsalias in most cases except this new database I tried to connect to this tame it was overlooked by me.

Comment: Can happen to everyone ;-), that's why we are here :D

Answer (score 1):

As Munchi pointed out the issue was caused by wrong syntax. I used:

```
sqlplus -L user_name/tns_alias@Password @d:\my_bat_file\sql_script.sql
```

Instead of:

```
sqlplus -L user_name/Password@tns_alias @d:\my_bat_file\sql_script.sql
```

Answer (score -5):

Try to set ORACLE_SID inside of a script, and then try with sqlplus command.

```
set ORACLE_SID=testdb

sqlplus -l....
```

Comment: Wouldn't matter since he is using a tnsalias.